# All Email Send Through Postmark Are Queued on Postmark Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, postmark

I have used CI with Postmark app to send email.
I have used CI mail functionality with postmark app.
I have used their SMTP feature to send email.

Email are being sent but all the emails are being queued on post mark server.
Any idea why this is happening?

BTW i am using free account and I have 25000 credits.

Comment: Try with [sendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/). As well to ask better question post some related code too

Comment: https://postmarkapp.com/contact

Answer (score 4):

The only documentation I could find from Postmark was this:

> You may (or may not) notice a new status type. We’ve added the status **In Queue** to specify if the message is currently waiting to be sent by Postmark. Right now, this just means that we’re waiting to send it to the mail server, but very soon we will even open this up so you can see the status on the mail server as well. If volume spikes on our side or an ISP decides to limit connections, you will be able to see the status.
>
> *From https://postmarkapp.com/blog/tracking-sent-emails-and-content*

My guess is that messages get queued if:

- Postmark itself is under heavy load and can't process the volume of messages
- Postmark decides that sending messages to particular domains/providers might trigger rate limits, so some messages get delayed to stick within these limits
- Your messages appear to be suspicious in some way, and so messages get queued for their team to review your account and uncap it. This could possibly happen if your bounce rate is too high, messages look spammy, or you're a new account that has a sudden spike in sending rates.

We had about 1,000 messages get placed "In Queue" recently, but they seemed to all get properly processed within 1-2 hours when we checked the activity pane again later.